# Fire and Forget in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any event in C# like fire and forget for every min???

fire this method every minute.

```
    public void Earning()
    {
        var data= new Bussinesslayer().Getdata();
    }
```

Comment: Depending on what you are using (WinForms, WPF, etc.), there are several Timer implementations included in the .NET Framework which you can utilize for this purpose.

Comment: Specify the context whether WinForms/WPF/ASP.Net etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Timer class:
**Declaration:**

```
System.Timers.Timer _tmr;
```

**Initialization:**

```
_tmr = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

**Setting up:**

```
//Assigning the method that will be called
_tmr.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tmr_Elapsed);
//Setting the interval (in milliseconds):
_tmr.Interval = 1000;
```

**Starting the timer:**

```
_tmr.Start();
```

The function that will should have the same signature as in the example below:

```
void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Earning();
  //please note that here you are in another thread.
}
```

If you want to stop the timer you can use:

```
_tmr.Stop();
```

Comment: If you want to avoid having the extra method just to call your original method, you can solve this by using a lambda function. `_tmr.Elapsed += (sender, args) => this.Earning();`

Answer (score 1):

Use, for example, [Rx](http://introtorx.com/)

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
          .Subscribe(x => Earning());
```

No threading needed

Comment: thnx appriciate for answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Earning()
{
    var data= new Bussinesslayer().Getdata();

    // Wait a minute
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Wait();
    // Re-run this method
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Earning());
}
```

You'll need these includes:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```